# Can Javascript Prototype Pattern Performance Be Improved

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, prototype

I have read that creation of objects via prototypes is faster and uses less memory than closures because closures need to re-create all the functions. Then accessing a function that is on the object's prototype is a little slower because it needs to traverse the prototype chain further to find the function.

I am wondering if adding a reference in the constructor to the prototype function could increase performance with very minimal memory and initial setup impact. This can be achieved with something like this...

```
function Customer2(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greet = this.constructor.prototype.greet;
}
Customer2.prototype = {
    constructor: Customer2,
    greet: function () {
        return this.name + ' says hi!';
    }
};
```

Here I add a variable `this.greet` that references the prototype function to save on traversal time.

Could this be an effective method at increasing performance and keeping memory consumption low? Would this cause any side effects such as problems with inheritance?

JSPerf link: http://jsperf.com/prototype-pattern-local-reference

So far the JSPerf seems to slightly support the idea (except Firefox which seems to strongly favor closures for setup which doesn't make any sense, maybe I've done something wrong). Of course, this is a very small example with very few test samples, and it doesn't show memory consumption, but thought it might help.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance issue in your code? People make claims about performance all the time, and they're usually unfounded or at least overstated. So just because someone said that method lookup with prototypal inheritance is slow, doesn't mean it's true. Write idiomatic, readable code. That's more important than hacks that may or may not gain you a microsecond.

Comment: ...if you were to put functions directly on the objects like that, I'd suggest that you *not* put them on the `.prototype` as well. It'll just confuse people. Instead create regular functions and assign them in the constructor.

Comment: While I haven't done any tests to prove it... *i think* in theory using this.greet in the constructor might *improve* lookup time for the function call... but you also have much more reference pointers. You are storying a variable for every method, in every instance of a class. Yes they are just references, but I would think they would make a bigger memory footprint.

Comment: Most important thing to realize is that the code you write is not the code that runs. Modern engines do all sorts of crazy optimizing. Firefox is probably optimizing away the entire operation for that one test. Probably not something you can rely on in real-world situations.

Comment: Btw, just `this.greet = this.greet` would suffice to create the local property, and not rely on some `.constructor` values.

Comment: @Bergi that's the most confusing and amazing (simultaneously) piece of JS I've seen in this whole year.

Comment: @zerkms: Well, the whole idea is…

Comment: Maybe the following can help you get better performance: http://youtu.be/0wgDGTgOPds

Comment: So far there isn't any issue with performance in my code. I've just been reading on the trade-offs of different patterns and this idea came to me as a very simple way of getting the best of both worlds. If it legitimately was faster than the regular prototype pattern but still kept the memory usage down, I don't think the extra line of code is a big eye-sore and actually it might make it easier to read as you would see all the functions of the "class" in the constructor function.